# Why do I get 404 error when calling Ajax Load Function in Django?

Tags: html, jquery, django, ajax, http-status-code-404

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKOZD.png) [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SSZ4.png) [Picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzBGX.png) I am building a page in Django that first renders a blank page with a loading picture, and then calls an Ajax get function to one of my views. Once my Ajax get function succeeds, it is supposed to load one of my HTML files. I get a 404 error saying that the template cannot be found, but the template is in the same folder as my other file. Is my file path wrong?

```
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

{% extends "stocks_sites/base.html" %}

 <!-- The loading image -->
  {% block loader %}
  <div id="loading">
      <p>Loading</p>
  </div>

  <div id="articles">
  </div>

<script>
    // AJAX call when page has loaded
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "{% url 'stocks_sites:get_news_articles' %}",

            success: function(response) {
              const news_articles = response;  
              const posts = news_articles.posts;
              const search = news_articles.search;

              document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
              $("#articles").load("news_articles.html");             
              
            }
        });
    });
</script>
{% endblock loader %}
```

Comment: @DreamBold I've already tried an assortment of file paths like that, but it is still not able to find the file. Could it be because I am using Django that I would have to specify a different file path?

Comment: One more thing. Stocks_sites is not the root folder. Everything is located in one big folder called stocks_emailer.

Comment: Can you update the screenshot of the folder structure?

Comment: @DreamBold I have updated it.

Comment: https://github.com/archatas/django-include-by-ajax

I think this will solve your problem!

Comment: Add a url for rendering news_articles.html then use that url to load data